# converting byte[] to byte

Tags: c#, byte

Can someone explain the difference in C# between a 'byte' and 'byte[]'?  My confusion is why I can't assign a single byte element out of the byte[] array into a variable defined as type 'byte'.

For example, this works:

```
byte binSize;
binSize = br.ReadByte();
```

But this does not:

```
byte binSize1;
binSize1 = br.ReadBytes(1);
```

I've looked at the [Microsoft Binary Reader class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and I see that the first example returns a single byte and the second returns an array of bytes.  I get it.  But is there some easy way to convert the single byte read in by 'ReadBytes' and cast it so that it can be stored in a 'byte' variable?

This is a problem when I want to convert what I read into an integer.  Only the line with 'binSize' below will work, the line with 'binSize1' will not.

```
txt.Text = BitConverter.ToInt16(binSize, 0).ToString(); 
txt.Text = BitConverter.ToInt16(binSize1, 0).ToString();
```

The error I get with the second line is 'Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte'

Comment: `br.ReadBytes(1)[0];`

Comment: It takes two bytes to represent a int16. are you sure you need to be converting a single byte?

Comment: The return type of the function `ReadBytes(int n)` is fixed to `byte[]`, even if `n = 1` it will return a 1-byte element array. It doesn't change its return value type based on the input `n`. Just derefence the first element of the array to get that byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain the difference in C# between a `byte` and `byte[]`?

The difference is the same as between `T` and `T[]` with all other types: `T` is a single item, while `T[]` is an array.

> is there some easy way to convert the single byte read in by `ReadBytes()` and cast it so that it can be stored in a `byte` variable?

If you know that a function returns an array with exactly one byte, apply `[0]` to its return value:

```
binSize1 = br.ReadBytes(1)[0];
```

Note that this approach is unsafe, because you don't know for certain that `br.ReadBytes(1)` has at least one byte. It is better to do a separate check:

```
var bytes = br.ReadBytes(1);
if (bytes.Length == 1) {
    var binSize1 = bytes[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight.  I understood conceptually the difference between the single byte versus array of bytes, what I was trying to figure out was how to get a single byte from the array saved to a 'byte'.  The key that I was missing was applying the '[0]' on the end of the ReadBytes(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of bytes, you obviously can't store it in *a single byte*. You can however store a given item of that collection, say, the first one:

```
byte myByte = byteArray[0];
```

Or without an array

```
 byte myByte = byteCollection.First();
```

Of course, you should probably make sure there *is* a first one before trying to grab it. The `Length` property of arrays is a good place to start.